# Звуки в javaFX. Можно ли добавить звуки в java?

Tags: java, javafx, аудио

Можно ли добавить звуки в javaFX, и как это зделать?
Если можно напишите пример.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
String file = "musicfile.mp3";
Media sound = new Media(new File(file).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё способ:

```
try {     
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("path_to_file"));

    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

    clip.open(ais);
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();

    Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    clip.stop();
    clip.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Запускайте из отдельного потока, чтобы не зависало окно JavaFX во время воспроизведения.
Вот простенький пример:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button playSoundBtn = new Button("Play");
        StackPane root = new StackPane(playSoundBtn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        StackPane.setAlignment(playSoundBtn, Pos.CENTER);
        playSoundBtn.setOnAction(event -> new SoundThread("Sound").start());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Window");
        stage.setMinHeight(300);
        stage.setMinWidth(400);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    static class SoundThread extends Thread {
        SoundThread(String name) {super(name);}

        public void run() {
            windowsBackgroundSound();
        }
        private void windowsBackgroundSound() {
            try {
                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Windows\\Media\\Windows Background.wav"));

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                clip.open(ais);
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();

                Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
                clip.stop();
                clip.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```